# ASP.NET Webapp -- asp:HyperLink with a background image shows has a border in IE but not FireFox

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

I have the following code in a ASP.NET master page:

```
<div id="hyperlinkimage"><asp:HyperLink ID="SomeHyperLink" runat="Server" NavigateUrl="~/Pages/Dashboard.aspx" ImageUrl="~/images/some_image.jpg" BorderWidth="0px" BorderStyle="None"/></div>
```

However, this image still has a blue border in IE, but not Firefox.  Do any of the erudite developers of StackO know of this issue or how to rectify it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

IE adds a border around images by default. If you don't like this behaviour, just specify in your css something like this:

```
img { border:none; }
```

This has nothing to do with asp.net tho...

Answer (score 1):

Add  style="border:none" to your ImageUrl.  Here is the modification below.

```
<div id="hyperlinkimage"><asp:HyperLink ID="SomeHyperLink" runat="Server" NavigateUrl="~/Pages/Dashboard.aspx" ImageUrl="~/images/some_image.jpg" BorderWidth="0px" BorderStyle="None" style="border:none"/></div>
```

Comment: One of the worst practices out there - mix html with css.

Comment: Walther, nemoze to bit horsie nez moja slovencina ale toto neni az take zle.  Zmiesanie CSS and HTML, mozno.  Zmiesanie CSS and ASPX, mato vyhody.  Tiez, preco Slovensky? Jeden Slovak ku druhemu, nie? =)

Comment: not sure if it doesn't violate rules of SO, so I'd rather reply in English. Maybe it will help others understand as well. Mixing css with aspx is the same evil as mixing css with html. Why? Because you still mix markup language with styles. There are no real advantages of doing it. Either way, this particular question requires a global solution, because this "feature" of IE affects EVERY image on the website. How would you achieve a fix with control attributes you suggested? Add them to every single image? You must surely see it's a wrong approach...